# Removing a sprite when it goes off-screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I have a sprite that goes from left to right on the screen, when it goes off screen it won't be back. Where is the best place to deallocate it? In the -update method? Or?

Comment: Hey, How do you check that sprite goes out off screen? , by continuously checking its position in update: ? (it's apart from your question!)

Comment: Well is there any other (more efficient ) way?

Answer (score 2):

you can use the didSimulatePhysics method. It is called after the update method. That we you can be sure that whatever needs to be finished in the update methods gets done, and then clean your objects or cycle through them and figure out which ones need to be removed.

```
 - (void)didSimulatePhysics {

    [self removeAllObstacles];
}

- (void)removeAllObstacles {

    [blocks removeAllChildren];

    [gameLayer enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"baddies" usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop) {

        if (node.position.x < - 100)
            [node removeFromParent];
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It has to be added in the update method only. Because The `update:` method will be called automatically by Sprite Kit for each frame.

Comment: This kinda seems inefficient... is there no other way?